# how to open CLI during installation

Tags: command-line, system-installation

I am maybe an idiot but I cannot find a standard bulletproof keyboard shortcut for opening the CLI / Terminal during ubuntu 14.* desktop installation.

and how to close it after im done?

so please help.. :(

Comment: during ubuntu installation, while I am installing ubuntu...

Comment: oh yea I already did it, i just cant remember what I pressed exactly, it was something with ctrl + some F key. And i need it before the "restart now" step, the last step

Comment: I'm not sure, Alt+F2 may be?

Comment: i dont know, thats why I ask about the right way and the real shortcut. thats why i posted the question to get a direct answer hopefully..

Comment: But did you try the above?

Comment: Ron i am not installing it right now, i am asking this for future reference because i will need it soon, i dont want to try anything now, but need a direct answer from someone who knows it.. I will note yours down and how do you close it after you done with the terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TTY` access on the installer is the same as on regular Ubuntu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1-6</kbd> (F keys ,one through six).

Terminal emulator (GUI terminal) is available only in the `Try Ubuntu` mode, not when installer is running.

To return to the GUI use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: ok, I open it with crtl + alt + F1 - F6, just how do i close it exactly?

Comment: It should be ctrl + alt + F7 to close it / to return back

Comment: for reference, in my 18.04 installation, the GUI is F1

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer true that "Terminal emulator (GUI terminal) is available only in the Try Ubuntu mode". On `ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> at any stage of the installer to open a terminal window.