# Ubuntu Core for Raspberry Pi 3, How to access MAC address before finishing setup?

Tags: system-installation, raspberrypi

So I've been having a weird issue where my university wifi won't let me complete the set up because it redirects all activity from a device to their login page until you either log in or confirm it's MAC address on a separate device.
Unfortunately I can't access the MAC address until after finishing set up, so I'm in a bit of a bind.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to escape to a shell using the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>.  See: [how to open CLI during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735410/how-to-open-cli-during-installation)

You can then find the MAC address using the `ifconfig` command.

I'm not sure the video is up-to-date, but looking at [this video showing the setu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gxg2r-BmvrQ)p, the MAC is actually displayed during the setup:
[image: Ubuntu Core Raspberry Pi3 setup screenshot from youtube]

If you can enable (whitelist) the access control limitation to your device's MAC using a different computer, that's probably easier.
Alternatively, you can also use x-windows enabled version of Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi to completed the MAC address whitelisting before moving to install Ubuntu Core.